# Promise.all([ anotherPromise, anotherPromise ]) when nesting promises the parent is not blocking

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In the following example `get_bc_templates()` returns before `get_bc_template()`.

```
async get_bc_templates(mfpns, cnetDB, cb) {
    const templates = await Promise.all([mfpns.map(async item => await this.get_bc_template(item, cnetDB))]);
    if (cb) {
        console.log(`prints immediately. before get_bc_template`.green.bold, templates)
        return cb(200, templates.map(template => template.bigCommerce_object))
    }
}




async get_bc_template(mfpn, cnetDB, cb ?) {
    console.log('this logs after the get_bc_templates already returns', mfpn);
    let collective_product = {
        CNET_data: promised_data[1],
        JAX_data: JAX_data,
        suggested_retail: await this.calc_suggested_retail(JAX_data),
        }
    return collective_product;
}
```

I need help rewriting this so `get_bc_templates` returns an array of `get_bc_template() => collective_product` (get_bc_template() works great one at a time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Promise.all` requires an array as argument, what you are passing is an array of an array:
`[mfpns.map(async item => await this.get_bc_template(item, cnetDB))]`

The map function already returns an array. So, what you have is an array of promises inside an array: `Promise.all([[promise, anotherPromise, ...]])`

Therefore `Promise.all` will try to await the array only, and not the promises inside.

You should remove the array brackets around the `map` function:

```js
const templates = await Promise.all(mfpns.map(async item => await this.get_bc_template(item, cnetDB)));
```

Comment: thanks alot. follow up ==> The console.log in `get_bc_template ` prints at the right time with the correct data... But the parent function has `undefined` foreach... any ideas?

Comment: @Omar I think it's likely related to the fact that you are trying to access `template.bigCommerce_object` which isn't a key you define on the object being returned in `get_bc_template()`. The only keys you have on the templates are `CNET_data`, `JAX_data`, and `suggested_retail`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing an array of promises to `Promise.all`, you're passing an array of arrays (the inner array is constructed by `map`, the outer by the `[]` literal). You should be doing

```
async get_bc_templates(mfpns, cnetDB) {
    const templates = await Promise.all(mfpns.map(item => this.get_bc_template(item, cnetDB)));
    console.log(`prints immediately. before get_bc_template`.green.bold, templates)
    return templates.map(template => template.bigCommerce_object);
}
```

Comment: Forgive my pedantry, but can it be called an array of *arrays* when it's an array that can only ever contain exactly one array? :P

Comment: @Klaycon the pedantic answer: Yes, we can, if we refer to the type not to the value. Even `[]` might be an array of numbers, although it doesn't contain one - and it's different from a `[]` or `[[]]` that is an array of arrays of promises for something.

Comment: Fair point, but in a language like javascript where the types can vary, I think it makes sense to refer to exactly what it contains.